# How similarity transformation is related to coordinate transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I know that every matrix can be transformed into its Jordan form using similarity transformation. But I wanted to know, this transformation is related to shifting of coordinate systems?

Comment: You're correct.

Comment: But can any one explain how this coordinate shifting is related to similarity transformation and how this thing work ?

Comment: This is related and might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627604/coordinate-transformations

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997256/meaning-of-similar-transformations/1997282#1997282