# Meaning of similar transformations

Tags: linear-transformations

I am studying similar transformations, and was trying to understand what it means.  If you have a linear transformation in given basis, this basis is same for input and output spaces, now when you change the basis, you get a new transformation matrix which is similar to the earlier transformation matrix, say $A$. Am I correct? And when you calculate $P$ and $P^{-1}$ and perform $PAP^{-1}$, the $P^{-1}$ converts the input in first basis to input in second basis. Am I right? If not what is the need for $P^{-1}$?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855995/how-similarity-transformation-is-related-to-coordinate-transformation See also comments with links there.

Answer (score 2):

*Note:* If you talk about similarity the input space of $A$ is the same as its output space. Otherwise you could not apply $P$ from the left and $P^{-1}$ from the right.

*Answer:* Yes, you can interpret similarity transformations as a change of basis.

Consider the equation $y = A x$ with a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, column vectors $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ as variables, and a coordinate transformation $\bar y = P y$, $\bar x = P x$. This leads to the equation 
\begin{align*}
P^{-1}\bar y &= AP^{-1} \bar x\\
\bar y &= \underbrace{PAP^{-1}}_{:=\bar A}\; \bar x
\end{align*}

*Example:*
Probably the most important similarity transformation is that one to *Jordan normal form*.

*Eigenvalues* of a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are the complex numbers $\lambda$ for which the
matrix

\begin{align*}
\mathbf1\lambda - A
\end{align*}

is singular ($\mathbf1$ stands for the identity matrix). The
geometrical multiplicity of $\lambda$ is the nullity of the matrix
$\mathbf1\lambda-A$, i.e., the dimension of its kernel.

The *algebraic multiplicity* of $\lambda$ is the nullity of $(\mathbf1\lambda-A)^n$.

Eigenvalues and their geometrical multiplicities are **invariant w.r.t. similarity transformations** $\bar A = PAP^{-1}$ since for any regular matrix $P$ the
matrices $\mathbf1\lambda-A$ and $P(\mathbf1\lambda-A)P^{-1}$ have the
same rank and expanding $P(\mathbf1\lambda-A)P^{-1}$ yields

\begin{align*}
P(\mathbf1\lambda-A)P^{-1} &= P\mathbf1 P^{-1}\lambda - PAP^{-1} = \mathbf1\lambda - \bar A,
\end{align*}

which shows that $\mathbf1\lambda-\bar A$ also has the same rank as $P(\mathbf1\lambda-A)P^{-1}$ and $\mathbf1\lambda-A$. 
The algebraic multiplicity is also invariant w.r.t. similarity transformation since the rank
of $(\mathbf 1\lambda - A)^k$ is also the same as that one of $(\mathbf1\lambda - \bar A)^k$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$. This is true for the case $k=1$ and follows for any $k$ by induction from

\begin{align*}
P(\mathbf1\lambda - A)^kP^{-1} &= P(\mathbf1\lambda-A)P^{-1}P(\mathbf1\lambda - A)^{k-1}P^{-1} = (\mathbf1\lambda - \bar A)P(\mathbf1\lambda - A)^{k-1}P^{-1}.
\end{align*}

For any matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ there is a base of complex *generalized eigenvectors* $v^{(1)},\ldots,v^{(n)}\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$ such that the coordinatized matrix $\bar A$ w.r.t. this base has
the block-diagonal form

\begin{align*}
\bar A = \begin{pmatrix}
J_1 &\mathbf 0 & \ldots &\mathbf 0\\
\mathbf0 & J_2 & \ddots  &\vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots &\mathbf 0 \\
\mathbf0 & \ldots &\mathbf0& J_n
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

where each of the Jordan blocks $J_k$ has the structure

\begin{align*}
J_k &= \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_k & 1           & 0             & \ldots        & 0      \\
0       & \ddots        & \ddots        & \ddots        & \vdots \\
\vdots  & \ddots        & \ddots        & \ddots        & 0      \\
\vdots  &               & \ddots        & \ddots        & 1      \\
0       & \ldots        & \ldots        & 0             & \lambda_k
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

with some $\lambda_k\in\mathbb{C}$ and size $\mu_k\in\mathbb{N}$ $(1\leq \mu_k \leq n)$. These $\lambda_k$ are just the eigenvalues of $\bar A$ and $A$ since the part occupied by $J_k$ in $\bar A$ becomes the singular matrix

\begin{align*}
\mathbf1\lambda_k - J_k =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \ddots &  0 \\
\vdots & & & \ddots & 1 \\
0 & & \ldots & & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

One easily sees that $\mathbf1\lambda_k-J_k$ applied to a vector $v=(v_1,\ldots,v_{\mu_k})^T\in\mathbb{C}^{\mu_k}$ dismisses the first component, shifts $v_2,\ldots,v_{\mu_k}$ one position to the front, and zeros out the last component: $(\mathbf1\lambda_k-J_k)\cdot v = (v_2,\ldots,v_{\mu_k},0)^T$. Any vector $v\in\mathbb{C}^{\mu_k}$ is nullified after $(\mathbf1\lambda_k-J_k)$ is applied $\mu_k$ -times. Therefore, the geometrical multiplicity of and eigenvalue $\lambda_k$ of $\bar A$ is the sum of the sizes of all Jordan-blocks for this eigenvalue.

If all Jordan blocks have size 1 the matrix is diagonalizable and the generalized eigenvectors are just *eigenvectors*.

*Example:*
In the following example two well motivated consecutive similarity transformation are employed to get to the Jordan normal form.

Two masses freely movable into one direction and interconnected by a spring without the influence of external forces can be described by the equations

\begin{align*}
\dot x_1 &= v_1\\
\dot v_1 &= \frac{k}{m_1}(x_2-x_1)\\
\dot x_2 &= v_2\\
\dot v_2 &= \frac{k}{m_2}(x_1-x_2)
\end{align*}

or written in matrix form

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot x_1\\
\dot v_1\\
\dot x_2\\
\dot v_2
\end{pmatrix} &=
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
0& 1& 0& 0\\
-\frac{k}{m_1}& 0 & \frac{k}{m_1}& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1\\
\frac{k}{m_2}& 0 & -\frac{k}{m_2}& 0
\end{pmatrix}}_{=:K}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
v_1\\
x_2\\
v_2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

where $K$ is the normalized stiffness matrix (short: stiffness matrix). The motion can be decomposed into that one of the center of mass $\bar x = \frac{m_1 x_1 + x_2 m_2}{m_1 + m_2}$ and a relative displacement $\Delta x = x_1 - x_2$. The full transformation for this decomposition is

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\bar x\\
\bar v\\
\Delta x\\
\Delta v
\end{pmatrix} =
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{m_1}{m_\Sigma}& 0 & \frac{m_2}{m_\Sigma} & 0\\
0 &\frac{m_1}{m_\Sigma}& 0 & \frac{m_2}{m_\Sigma}\\
1&0&-1&0\\
0&1&0&-1
\end{pmatrix}}_{=:T}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
v_1\\
x_2\\
v_2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

with $m_\Sigma := m_1 + m_2$. Note that for determining the inverse $T^{-1}$ one exploits that the system is composed of two independent subsystems for the locations $x$ and the velocities $v$. These two subsystems have the same transformation matrix $T_x:=\begin{pmatrix}m_1/m_\Sigma & m_2/m_\Sigma\\1& -1\end{pmatrix}$ with the inverse $T_x^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1& m_2/m_\Sigma\\ 1& - m_1/m_\Sigma\end{pmatrix}$. Combining the transformation matrices for the subsystems we obtain the transformation matrix for the overall system

\begin{align*}
T&:=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{m_1}{m_\Sigma}& 0 & \frac{m_2}{m_\Sigma} & 0\\
0 &\frac{m_1}{m_\Sigma}& 0 & \frac{m_2}{m_\Sigma}\\
1&0&-1&0\\
0&1&0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

The stiffness matrix in the new coordinates becomes

\begin{align*}
\bar K_\Delta &:= T K T^{-1}\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{m_1}{m_\Sigma}& 0 & \frac{m_2}{m_\Sigma} & 0\\
0 &\frac{m_1}{m_\Sigma}& 0 & \frac{m_2}{m_\Sigma}\\
1&0&-1&0\\
0&1&0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0& 1& 0& 0\\
-\frac{k}{m_1}& 0 & \frac{k}{m_1}& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1\\
\frac{k}{m_2}& 0 & -\frac{k}{m_2}& 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \frac{m_2}{m_\Sigma} & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 &  \frac{m_2}{m_\Sigma}\\
1 & 0 & -\frac{m_1}{m_\Sigma} & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 &  -\frac{m_1}{m_\Sigma}
\end{pmatrix}
\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
0& 1 & 0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 0 & 1\\
0& 0 & -\frac{k}{m_{\rm r}}& 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

with the reduced mass $m_{\rm r}:=\frac{m_1m_2}{m_1+m_2}$.
The corresponding system

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot {\bar x}\\
\dot {\bar v}\\
\Delta \dot x\\
\Delta \dot v
\end{pmatrix}
&= \begin{pmatrix}
0& 1 & 0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 0 & 1\\
0& 0 & -\frac{k}{m_{\rm r}}& 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\bar x\\
\bar v\\
\Delta x\\
\Delta v
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

is already split into two independent subsystems for the center of mass motion

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{\bar x} \\
\dot{\bar v}
\end{pmatrix} &=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
{\bar x} \\
{\bar v}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

and the relative displacement

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\Delta\dot x\\
\Delta\dot v
\end{pmatrix}
&=
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
-\frac{k}{m_{\rm r}}& 0
\end{pmatrix}}_{=:K_\Delta}
\begin{pmatrix}
\Delta x\\
\Delta v
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

The system matrix for the center of mass motion has already the form of a Jordan block with size 2 and eigenvalue 0.
For transforming the second diagonal block $K_\Delta$ to Jordan normal form one solves the eigenvalue equation

\begin{align*}
0 &= \operatorname{det}(\mathbf1\lambda-K_\Delta) = \operatorname{det}
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & -1\\
\frac{k}{m_{\rm r}} & \lambda
\end{pmatrix} = \lambda^2 + \frac{k}{m_{\rm r}}
\end{align*}

which has the solutions $\lambda_\pm = \pm i\sqrt{\frac{k}{m_{\rm r}}} = \pm i\omega$ with $\omega:= \sqrt{\frac{k}{m_{\rm r}}}$ and the imaginary unit $i=\sqrt{-1}$.
The corresponding eigenvectors $u_\pm$ are nontrivial solutions of the singular system

\begin{align*}
\left(\mathbf1\lambda_\pm - K_\Delta\right) u_\pm &= \mathbf0\\
\begin{pmatrix}
\pm i \omega & -1\\
\omega^2 & \pm i\omega
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{1\pm}\\
u_{2\pm}
\end{pmatrix}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

such as

\begin{align*}
u_\pm &=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
\pm i\omega
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

The action of the matrix $K_\Delta$ on the eigenvectors $v_\pm$ is just a scaling $K_\Delta u_+ = i\omega\, u_+$, $K_\Delta u_- = -i\omega\, u_-$.
If we combine these two equations in the columns of a matrix equation we obtain

\begin{align*}
K_\Delta
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
u_+ & u_-
\end{pmatrix}}_{=:T_\Delta}
&= \begin{pmatrix}
i\omega u_+ & -i\omega u_-
\end{pmatrix}
=
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
u_+ & u_-
\end{pmatrix}}_{=T_\Delta}
\begin{pmatrix}
i\omega & 0\\
0 & -i\omega
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

and left-multiplication with $T_\Delta^{-1}$ gives the wanted similarity transformation into a diagonal matrix

\begin{align*}
T_\Delta^{-1} K_\Delta T_\Delta &= \begin{pmatrix}
i\omega & 0\\
0 & -i\omega
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}